# How can I search the latest transaction of specific account in a ERC20 contract?

Tags: web3js

Here is the [TUSD smart ERC20 contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0x8dd5fbce2f6a956c3022ba3663759011dd51e73e), if I have a transaction hash, how can search the transaction history with this transaction hash?

right now the only way I can think is to get the whole history, but that doesn't seem to be effecient as shown

```
contractAddress = "0x00.."
web3.eth.filter({
address: contractAddress
from: 1,
to: 'latest'
}).get(function (err, result) {
// callback code here
})
```

Comment: there is not history for this transaction hash because transaction hash is unique and it only happens once in a lifetime

Comment: so if the user submits a transaction, and he gives me the transaction hash, how could I search the transaction with this transaction hash in order to verify the transaction is complete?

Comment: you can use the `Status` or `transactionIndex` field, returned by `eth.getTransaction(hash)`, however the proper call would be `getTransactionReceipt(hash)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepting a user provided tx hash and want to know the status of the transaction, you should use the `eth_getTransactionReceipt` method.

If no transaction receipt is found, the transaction has not been mined yet. If a transaction receipt is found, it will contain the status (1 for success, 0 for failure), and any logs emitted by the transaction, which should be an ERC20 transfer event in this case.